# Programmatically create a new document based on a content type template

Tags: content-type, 2013, document

As in the title, I need to programmatically create a new document based on a content type template. Does anyone know the best way to do this? Normally, to add files you use `Web.Files.Add()`, but all those overloads take a byte stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
var tplurl = doclib.ContentTypes["MyContentType"].DocumentTemplateUrl;
byte[] stream = web.GetFile(tplurl).OpenBinary();

SPFile file = myFolder.Files.Add("myFileName", stream, true);
```

Comment: The above code give problems for the .docx files as file is could not be opened? any ideas.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using a docx as template for my content type not a dotx.