# Disable empty file rejection

Tags: 2013, document

Is it possible to disable the (extremely annoying) behavior of SharePoint whereby it rejects "empty" documents? I need to do this because I'm [programmatically creating documents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60506/programmatically-create-a-new-document-based-on-a-content-type-template) where the template may be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to disable this behavior, however, I was able to upload an empty template file to SharePoint using SharePoint designer. In my case this should suffice.